# Is a convolution of an $L^2[0,\infty)$ function $L^2[0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convolution

Suppose $f\in L^2[0,\infty)$. Is $\int_0^x f(y)e^{-(x-y)}dy\in L^2[0,\infty)$? What if we replace $e^{-x}$ by a general $L^2[0,\infty)$ function?

---

Had $L^2[0,\infty)$ been replaced by $L^1[0,\infty)$, the answer is affirmative. Let $\mathcal L[f]$ be the Laplace transform of $f$, we have $\mathcal L[f*g]=\mathcal L[f]$$\mathcal L[g]$. But I do not see how this helps in answering the question.

Comment: I guess [Young's convolution inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality) might help resolve the first part.

Comment: $f*f$ need not be in $L^{2}$ for $f$ in $L^{2}$. Example $f=\hat {g}$ where $g(x)=x^{-1/4} I_{(0,1)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(y)e^{-(x-y)}dy$ in $L^2$? The Laplace transform $\mathscr{L}\{F\}$ is $\mathscr{L}\{f\}\mathscr L\{e^{-x}\}$, and
$$
      \mathscr{L}\{e^{-x}\}=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-sx}e^{-x}dx=\frac{1}{s+1}
$$
$f\in L^2[0,\infty)$ iff $\mathscr{L}\{f\}$ is in the Hardy class $H^2(R)$ on the right half-plane $R$. Multiplying by $\frac{1}{s+1}$ gives another function that is in $H^2$, which means that $F \in L^2$.

The Laplace transform of the convolution $f\star g$, where $f,g\in L^2[0,\infty)$, is the product of two functions in $H^2$. Such a product is not necessarily in $H^2$, which means $f\star g$ is not necessarily in $L^2[0,\infty)$. For example,
$$
       F(s) = \frac{1}{s^{2/5}(1+s)} \in H^2,
$$

but $F(s)F(s)\notin H^2$.

Comment: +1 and accepted! Very fitting and instructive introducing the Hardy space for the square integrable function on the half real line. The comments of SangchulLee and KaviRamaMurthy at the top nicely complement this answer.